# Disable the NSAlert button when suppression button is checked

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I have an `NSAlert` with `setShowsSuppressionButton:YES` for a checkbox and two buttons named `OK` and `Cancel`. How would I make the `Cancel` button to become disabled whenever we click(check) on the suppression button?

Comment: Isn't `NSAlert` only for MacOS? Why are you tagging it `ios`?

Comment: I have the same question. Did you ever get an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the button and set the `action` and `target` atttributes of the `suppressionButton` :

```
alert = [[NSAlert alloc] init];
[alert setMessageText:@"text"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"OK"];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Cancel"];
[alert.buttons[0] setEnabled:NO];
[alert setShowsSuppressionButton:YES];
[alert.suppressionButton setTitle:@"You need to activate me first"];
[alert.suppressionButton setTarget:self];
[alert.suppressionButton setAction:@selector(selectClicked:)];
[alert runModal];
```

In the action handler you can then toggle the `enabled` attribute of the button based on the state of the checkbox:

```
-(IBAction)selectClicked:(NSButton *)sender {
    for (NSView *view in sender.superview.subviews) {
        if ([view isKindOfClass:[NSButton class]]) {
            NSButton *button = (NSButton *)view;
            if ([button.title isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {
                button.enabled = (sender.state == NSControlStateValueOn);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set a boolean once the suppression button is active and check for that when creating the alert or check for it with a if else statement creating one of two different alerts, one with and one with out cancel.

Comment: Thanx for you answer rezand. My question is how can i know when user checked only the checkbox?? Where to set the BOOL.I just want that when alert appears and user clicks on only the checkbox nothing else then cancel button should become disable(fade).

Comment: sorry i reread the question and finally got a visual in my head of exactly what you're asking/doing, im not familiar with nsalerts but comparing to my experience with ios programming you should be able to set button to  = nil instead of "cancel" after the check box receives an action, i just hope this leads you in the right direction if i find anymore information ill try to help out more.

Comment: Thanx again. But my main concern is how can i receive an action for the check box coz its a default property of an NSAlert.

Comment: i know that you can check the state once done i was trying to look if it had delegation to call something like a ibaction and really couldnt find anything with out making a custom fake nsalert but if you want a hack for now i suppose you could throw together a timer to keep checking state once the nsalert goes up and then ends when its gone. ive seen others check state with something like this... shouldSuppress = [[alert suppressionButton] state] == NSOnState;